# Django. Create a popup window

Tags: django, popup

In django admin we have popup windows. They do their work when we hit little green plus on some admin pages. For example when we want to create another sample of our model.

My question is the following: **can I utilize somehow this mechanics in order to create my own popup window when some link or button is hit?** Right now a new tab opens. I would like to have a popup window.

I saw a boolean option which i can render in the context, which is called is_popup. Maybe i should use it? Unfortunately when i just set it to True right now, it does not toggle a popup window. Just another tab.

EDIT:
Some code I have:

```
def apply_to_brands(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    mylist = list(queryset.values("id"))

    ids = []
    for _ in mylist:
        ids.append(str(_.get('id')))
    request.session['user_ids'] = ids
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    app_label = opts.app_label
    data = {
        'brands': brands,
        'opts': opts,
        'change': True,
        'is_popup': False,
        'save_as': False,
        'has_delete_permission': False,
        'has_add_permission': False,
        'has_change_permission': False,
        'app_label': app_label,
    }
    return render_to_response("admin/brand/brand/brand_list.html", data)
```

the template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_static admin_modify %}
{% block title %}
Apply users to brand
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Select brands</h1>
{% for brand in brands %}
<li>
    <a href="http://localhost/admin/user/user/{{brand.id}}/apply/">{{ brand }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to include some code of what you tried.

Comment: @JeanBouvattier, added some code.

Comment: Best way to create a popup is not really Django-specific. Use `modal`  : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp

Comment: Actually your problem has little to do with Django or even template. You should rather look into html and JS related subject

Answer (score 1):

For reference: The code for opening popups for related objects (e.g. green plus) lives in [`RelatedObjectLookups.js`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/52b054824e899db40ba48f908a9a00dadc56cb89/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js#L36). You probably do not want or need to use this. It deals with a lot of other stuff.

Instead you can just use `window.open()` like this to open a popup similar to what the django admin does:

```js
window.open("/some/path", "some-name", 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
```

You might want to have this in a function or use it inline in a template like this:

```html
<button data-href="/admin" onclick="window.open(this.dataset.href, 'my-new-popup', 'width=400,height=600,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">
    open popup
</button>
```

The [MDN docs for `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#opening_a_popup) have further information and examples.